# Unix tree ignore by pattern

Tags: unix, tree

`man tree` says

```
   -I pattern
          Do not list those files that match the wild-card pattern.
```

However, when I specify:

```
$ tree . -I .*~ -I *egg-info
```

I still see:

```
tree . -I .*~ -I *egg-info -I *.pyc
.
├── bin
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── Makefile~
```

etc., it's still showing `Makefile~` even though there's a terminal `~`

What's the right syntax to get tree to ignore the pattern I have given it?

Comment: shell based reg-ex would be `-I *~` but not sure if `tree` is using "full" regex or the simpler shell version. Also may not hurt to quote those arguments,so the shell will not try to expand the `*` chars. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few possibilities in your command. (Not knowing the 'flavor' of your unix, it's hard to pinpoint exactly).

1. `.*` Unix has "hidden" files. These are files whose name starts with a DOT. In Reg Ex, DOT ASTERISK means *0 or more characters*. With file names, DOT ASTERISK means *all hidden files and no visible files*. `Makefile~` is a visible file, not a hidden file, so it will not be excluded. You may need to replace  DOT ASTERISK TILDE with ASTERISK TILDE.
2. `-I` = Exclude *files*, not exclude *directories*. If `Makefile~` is a directory name, the `-I` may not exclude it.
3. File Globbing can bite you. `-I M*` will read the current directory and expand `M*` into every filename in the **current directory**. So, `-I M*` couild be "globbed" (or replaced) with `-I Milk Money Margaret_is_a_Beauty`. Use quotation marks around your wildcards. Try `-I ".*~"`or `-I '.*~'`

Answer (score 0):

As per the man page extract you quoted, `tree` uses "wild-card pattern" which is a common synonym for "glob" or "glob pattern". In this paradigm `*` is the syntax for "a any number of any character".

(`.*` is the equivalent form in the regex paradigm.)

Your first ignore pattern `-I .*~` is then searching for a `.` character followed by a `*` then a `~`.

In this you simply mixed up the regex form with the glob form.

And as you can see, your other patterns worked the way you wanted because they don't have a prepended `.`  in them.